# how do I change the data types on my database

Tags: mysql, sql, database, apache

I am using MySQL that comes with Apache. I have imported an Excel spreadsheet into MySQL and created a database. However all the data is stored as varchar, when some are clearly numerical. How can I change the data-types of these specific entries?

Comment: Change the way you imported it.

Answer (score 2):

This will change the column to an integer.  Check the manual for any other data types you're interested in, and beware of potential data loss.

```
ALTER TABLE `mydatabase`.`mytable` CHANGE `myfield` `myfield` INT(10) NULL;
```

or, per Marcus' observation:

```
ALTER TABLE `mydatabase`.`mytable` MODIFY `myfield` CHAR(10) ;
```

Comment: `MODIFY` would be better so you don't have to specify the 'new' column name.

Comment: Good point....actually have never used that ... old habits die hard, so thanks!